# Green function power-law behavior in real and momentum space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, greens-functions

Given a Green's function with pawer-law behavior in $k$-space $g(k)\sim\frac{1}{k^a}$ (at least for small $k$), what is the asymptotic form for $g(x)$ in the real space?

In the paragraph above Eq. (56) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9307009.pdf), it is claimed that $g(x)\sim\frac{1}{x^a}$ in general (the rest of the paper does not seem to be relevant to this question). How to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple dimensional analysis. If $g(k) \sim 1/k^a$, then in real space $g(x)$ goes as
$$
g(x) \sim \int \frac{d^d k}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{e^{i k \cdot x}}{k^a} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^d} \int_0^{\infty} k^{d-1} dk \int_{S^{(d-1)}} d\Omega \frac{e^{ikx \cos \theta}}{k^a} = \frac{1}{x^{d-a}} \int_0^{\infty} d\ell \, \ell^{d-a-1} \int_{S^{(d-1)}} d\Omega \, e^{i \ell \cos \theta}
$$
where I've performed the change of integration variables $\ell = kx$. We therefore have the asymptotic scaling
$$
g(x) \sim \frac{1}{x^{d-a}}
$$
which could have been immediately inferred by dimensional analysis.

A couple notes:

- If you meant for $g(k) \sim 1/k^a$ and $g(x) \sim 1/x^a$ to decay with the same exponent in your question, then this would be in general incorrect. However, in Shankar's example, we have $d = 4$ and $a = 2$, so both $g(x)$ and $g(k)$ decay with exponent $-2$.
- In general, $g(k)$ might not be exactly a power law, but might be a sum of different power laws, or something even more complicated. The long-distance (i.e., large $x$) behavior of $g(x)$ is determined by the long-wavelength (i.e., small $k$) behavior of $g(k)$. So the asymptotic "$\sim$"s should be interpreted in the sense of the $k \to 0$ behavior of $g(k)$ and the $x \to \infty$ behavior of $g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer!